# Form POST data not passing through to PHP

Tags: php, forms, query-string

I'm stumped as to why my code isn't working. I've done POSTS a million times, but this time it just doesn't seem to work.

My form:

```
<form method="post" name="form" id="form" enctype="text/plain" action="../posts/">
    <fieldset id="inputs" style="text-align: center;">
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter password" required />Press enter to submit
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

My PHP code for retrieval:

```
if(isset($_POST['password'])){
    echo "success";
}
else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

I get "fail" every time. What am I doing wrong? I just cant see it.

Comment: Remove `enctype="text/plain" ` and check

Comment: Ugh, thank you Gautam3164. That was exactly right. My brain is fried, I should sleep. Thanks.

Comment: why do someone add `enctype="text/plain"`? doesn't make any sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **enctype="text/plain"** from the form it will submit.

```
<form method="post" name="form" id="form"  action="../posts/">
    <fieldset id="inputs" style="text-align: center;">
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter password" required />Press enter to submit
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove `enctype="text/plain"` and check like

```
<form method="post" name="form" id="form" action="../posts/">
    <fieldset id="inputs" style="text-align: center;">
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter password" required />Press enter to submit
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

enctype defines how the data should be formatted before sending. the two correct formats are `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (which essentially sends things as key=valye&anotherkey=anothervalue, with http headers) and `multipart/form-data` (which splits each key up into a distinct section of data). `text/plain` means nothing should be done - its behaviour is essentially undefined between browsers, and was only ever used for automated email forms in the days before spam.

Answer (score 0):

I agreed with @Gautam3164..You just remove `enctype="text/plain"` and check it out

```
<form method="post" name="form" id="form" enctype="text/plain" action="../posts/">
    <fieldset id="inputs" style="text-align: center;">
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter password" required />Press enter to submit
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and change into

```
 <form method="post" name="form" id="form"  action="../posts/">
        <fieldset id="inputs" style="text-align: center;">
            <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter password" required />Press enter to submit
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

and also refer this [FIDDLE](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3ucWbJ)